# Delphi2007 + TWWDB grid field conversion

Tags: delphi

I am using delphi 2007.
I want to show the user defined value for one of the  `TWWDBgrid**` field.

For eg: I want to show  `GENERAL` in the DB grid for the database value `1`

Can anybody help?

Comment: My approach would be to create a new table in the database using the DBGrid Value (and possibly userID if it is per user), link the field to the new table and change my query accordingly.

Comment: Use a calculated field in your table or query of type string, and use the OnCalcFields event for that table/query to assign the value you want to display based on your field's value.

Answer (score 0):

You could imbed a TwwDBComboBox into the TwwDBGrid within its ControlType property.

Drop a TwwDBCombo onto the same form as the Twwdbgrid. Select the Items property which will initially show "<0 Items>" (ignore the 3 Items shown in the image - I got lazy!).

[image]

Check the "Map Displayed Value to Stored Value". This is most important as it displays the grid. Add the values as shown. You only mention one value but maybe there are more values than just '1' on the database.

[image: Map '1' to 'GENERAL']

Then select the ControlType property of your TwwDBGrid.

[image: Changing the control control type]

Select the relevant database field from the list (I have not included the image), select the "Edit Control" tab, select "CustomEdit" from the "Control Type" drop down and in "Control Name", select the TwwDBCombo control you created above.

[image]

This approach will allow the user to change the field value using a drop down. If you don't want the user to change the value, then just check the Read-Only property of the DBCombo.

Comment: HI DavidG, thank u so much for your kind support. I tried the above solution , can u explain the following point once again 'add the Stored Value of "1" and set its Displayed Value to "General". ' Bcoz I am new to this tww tool.

Comment: @NAUFAL Have added some images that should guide you through the controls